How can I allow a user to add any number of custom user_meta fields on a WordPress front-end page?
I have a requirement to generate a rate calculator accessible to multiple users, each with their own set of criteria and values. I'm using user_meta fields to store the values for each user.
One element is a price threshold / rate pairing but each user may have a differing amount of thresholds so I can't simply fix a set amount of threshold / rate input fields. The user needs to be able to add these as required, one at a time.
eg.
[Property Price 1] / [Marketing Rate 1]
[ADD NEW RATE BUTTON]
[Property Price 2] / [Marketing Rate 2]
[ADD NEW RATE BUTTON]
[Property Price 3] / [Marketing Rate 3]
etc.
After clicking the [ADD NEW RATE BUTTON] it would need to generate a new custom user_meta pairing, numbered incrementally, so the above example would generate the following:
$property_price_1, $marketing_rate_1
$property_price_2, $marketing_rate_2
$property_price_3, $marketing_rate_3
etc.
I have it all working with fixed rate / threshold pairings, but I know the end users will have varying requirements, so don't want to limit them to eg. 10 rate / thresholds. Some may only have 2 or 3, others may have upwards of 20. Hence the need to be flexible with the amount.

Welcome to WPSE! To help us help you, please edit your question to include the code you'd like help with. Otherwise we'll all just be guessing.

To allow users to add any number of custom user_meta fields on a WordPress front-end page, you can approach this by using JavaScript for dynamic form generation and then handle the form submission with PHP to store the values in user_meta. Here’s how you can achieve this.

Create the Front-end Form
First, create the HTML form with a template for the price/rate pairs and a button to add more pairs


<form id="rate-calculator-form">
   <div id="rate-fields">
      <div class="rate-field">
         <input type="text" name="property_price_1" placeholder="Property Price 1">
         <input type="text" name="marketing_rate_1" placeholder="Marketing Rate 1">
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" id="add-rate">Add New Rate</button>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


Add JavaScript for Dynamic Fields
Use JavaScript to add more fields when the "Add New Rate" button is clicked:


let rateCounter = 1;

document.getElementById('add-rate').addEventListener('click', function() {
    rateCounter++;
    const newRateField = document.createElement('div');
    newRateField.classList.add('rate-field');
    newRateField.innerHTML = `
        
        
    `;
    document.getElementById('rate-fields').appendChild(newRateField);
});


Handle Form Submission in PHP
When the form is submitted, loop through the posted data and save each pair as a custom user_meta field:


add_action('wp_ajax_save_user_meta', 'save_user_meta');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_user_meta', 'save_user_meta');

function save_user_meta() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ($user_id && !empty($_POST)) {
        $i = 1;
        while (isset($_POST["property_price_{$i}"]) && isset($_POST["marketing_rate_{$i}"])) {
            $property_price = sanitize_text_field($_POST["property_price_{$i}"]);
            $marketing_rate = sanitize_text_field($_POST["marketing_rate_{$i}"]);

            update_user_meta($user_id, "property_price_{$i}", $property_price);
            update_user_meta($user_id, "marketing_rate_{$i}", $marketing_rate);

            $i++;
        }
        wp_send_json_success('Data saved successfully!');
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Unable to save data.');
    }
    wp_die();
}


Submit the Form with AJAX
Finally, submit the form using AJAX to prevent page reloads and handle the response:


jQuery('#rate-calculator-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                alert(response.data);
            } else {
                alert('Error: ' + response.data);
            }
        }
    });
});


Thanks for the help. Some of it's working but will need to come back to it next week. One issue I have is that when loading the page it needs to display all the rate / threshold pairings that have already been entered. There's also an issue with numbering the pairings. And I'm getting an error at the AJAX part - should the URL just be the same URL as the page? And how do you provide the response data?
